# How to merge rows with diff values into 1? (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

First post here and quite new to SQL - hopefully this isn't too much of a silly question but I would appreciate some help.

I have the following query:

```
select  
    t.staffID, t.lessonday, t.lessonstarttime, t.lessonendtime,
    t.classname, s.staffcontact1, s.staffcontact2 
from 
    wh.dbo.classmain t
left outer join 
    wh.dbo.staff s on s.staffid = t.staffID
where 
    t.staffID = '3453'
group by 
    t.staffID, t.lessonday, t.lessonstarttime, t.lessonendtime,
    t.classname, s.staffcontact1, s.staffcontact2
```

Which gives me the following results

```
  staffid lessonday lessonstarttime lessonendtime classname staffcontact1 staffcontact2 
1  3435     Tue          12:34         13:30         Eng         127            0   
2  3435     Tue          12:34         13:30         Eng         340            0
```

Now first of all for the reason of this query there should NEVER be any duplicates with the `staffID`, however in this instance a data quality issue has caused `staffcontact1` to have 2 separate entries (they should both be on the same line, so `staffcontact1` is `340` and staffcontact 2 is `127`)

How could I amend my code to edit all duplicates so where the `staffcontact1` is in a separate column, to put it into the `staffcontact2` thus taking away the duplication?

Comment: Add the missing commas (between columns, in the select list and in the group by clause.)

Answer (score 1):

If the most rows each staffID will have is 2 then use a `MAX` and `MIN` function.

Also cleaned up some missing commas etc.

Also not 100% on the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so try the second query first and see if it yields expected results.

```
SELECT t.staffID, t.lessonday, t.lessonstarttime, t.lessonendtime, t.classname, MIN(s.staffcontact1) AS staffcontact1, MAX(s.staffcontact1) AS staffcontact2
FROM wh.dbo.classmain t
LEFT OUTER JOIN wh.dbo.staff s ON s.staffid = t.staffID
WHERE t.staffID = '3453'
GROUP BY t.staffID, t.lessonday, t.lessonstarttime, t.lessonendtime, t.classname
```

Using `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT t.staffID, t.lessonday, t.lessonstarttime, t.lessonendtime, t.classname, MIN(s.staffcontact1) AS staffcontact1, MAX(s.staffcontact1) AS staffcontact2
FROM wh.dbo.classmain t
INNER JOIN wh.dbo.staff s ON s.staffid = t.staffID
WHERE t.staffID = '3453'
GROUP BY t.staffID, t.lessonday, t.lessonstarttime, t.lessonendtime, t.classname
```

Comment: `MAX(staffcontact2) As staffcontact2` will still be 0, will it not?  Should be `MAX(StaffContact1)`?

Comment: @TJB Woops! Thanks, fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

The true correct answer to this is to fix your data rather than fudge around it as follows:

Step 1: Remove the offending row

```
DELETE FROM wh.dbo.staff
WHERE staffID = '3453'
AND staffcontact1 = '127'
```

Step 2: Update the other record correctly:

```
UPDATE wh.dbo.staff
SET staffcontact2 = '127'
WHERE staffID = '3453'
```

Answer (score 0):

A question just like this has been answered this very same day. You want to look into using pivot.

[Join 2 tables and display by id,priority & number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763653/join-2-tables-and-display-by-id-priority-number)