# Join 2 tables and display by id,priority & number

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

Example tables and desired result:
The result table shown below is the output I actually want.

[image: 1]

tried the following query with pivot:

```
with pivot_data AS
(
  select client_id
        ,ph_type
        ,Ph_number
  from client_table
    inner join phone_table
      on client_table.phone_id = phone_table.ph_id
)
select *
from pivot_data
pivot (sum(ph_number)
       for ph_type in ('c','w','h')
      );
```

Result I got:

[image: 2]

Any help would be appreciated.
Answers in sql server would be great but oracle & mysql is also welcome if they can point me in the right direction. :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: mysql or sql-server or oracle?

Comment: I cannot see a question? You have some data - please format it as text (or even better as DML statements) - and a query and an output but you do not say what is wrong with it or what you are expecting instead... how are we supposed to even try to help you?

Comment: How many levels of priority can there be?  And why do you need your result in that format?  Is that not better suited to being formatted in your presentation layer?

Comment: @MT0 I have given the expected result in the first image link,and have attached the results I have managed to get in the second Image link.If you look at the result that I got vs the result in the example you can spot the difference.

Comment: @iamdave There can be n number of entries in the priority column in "client_table" , and I need the results in the particular format as shown in the example,  I have to export it as CSV & the target is in this format

Comment: And why do you need the data in this format from your SQL?  What application are you using to present the data?

Comment: @iamdave I am currently trying out this in oracle

Comment: No, I mean where will the data end up?  In an excel document, in a reporting suite, etc?  What you are trying to do goes against all sensibly SQL development, but is trivial for a reporting tool to transform a normal dataset into the format you want.

Comment: @iamdave  this gets exported as csv which is picked up by a SSIS package

Comment: ...for what purpose?  Why aren't you just exporting a normal dataset?  Why are you adding multiple columns?  The solution you have accepted below will break if you have more than 3 priorities and you will need to amend the SSIS procedure *every single time* the number increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT client_id, priority, phone_number, phone_type
  FROM   client_table c
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         phone_table p
         ON ( c.phone_id = p.phone_id )
)
PIVOT ( MAX( phone_type ) AS phonetype, MAX( phone_number ) AS phonenumber
        FOR priority IN ( 1 AS Prio1, 2 AS Prio2, 3 AS Prio3 ) );
```

**Output**:

```
 CLIENT_ID PRIO1_PHONETYPE PRIO1_PHONENUMBER PRIO2_PHONETYPE PRIO2_PHONENUMBER PRIO3_PHONETYPE PRIO3_PHONENUMBER
---------- --------------- ----------------- --------------- ----------------- --------------- -----------------
         1 C               9999999999        H               5555555555        W               7777777777
```

Comment: Dude this was what I wanted,Many thanks!! I had figured that I should be using pivot but being a bit green couldn't figure out how. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You really need to do some reading on [set based thinking](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/t-sql-foundations-thinking-sets) and how what you are asking for will be very detrimental to your maintenance of the SSIS solution moving forwards.

All you need to do is export the data as is.  If you absolutely have to have it all in the one CSV file, just `join` the two tables together and retain a normalised, scalable dataset that won't break if the number of priorities increases:

```
select c.client_id
        ,c.phone_id
        ,c.priority
        ,p.phone_type
        ,p.phone_number
from @Client c
    join @Phone p
        on c.phone_id = p.phone_id
```